# Key value assignment in the object passed as a parameter in a arrow function for map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In the below code, I am passing an array of objects in the map function. The Value of `category` gets assigned to `categoryName` and is returned as `categoryName`. My problem is understanding the assignment operation. Doesn't the assignment to **object properties** happen this way `key:value` ? Instead, I see that the value of `category` is assigned to this new Variable in this fashion `value:key`

```
const companies= [
  {name: "Company One", category: "Finance"},
  {name: "Company Two", category: "Retail"}
];
const companyu = companies.map(
({ name, category: categoryName }) => ({ name, categoryName }))
```

Comment: You're just creating an alias for `category`, while destructuring.

Comment: `{key: value}` act differently when using inside destructuring, `key:` is placeholder and variable name is value. I was watching @getify video the other day and he said that this may be confusing because it's like the opposite of object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ name, category: categoryName }`, despite looking exactly like an object literal, is not one. When written where an expression is expected, like `let x = { name, category: categoryName };`, that syntax creates an object, but when written where an argument name is expected, like `function foo({ name, category: categoryName }) {}` and like your example, it destructures an object.

Destructuring is a whole topic that you can [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) about, but the gist is, instead of a single name you write a pattern with some names in it, and that pattern is applied to the given value to set all the pattern's names. So, this

```
const {a, b} = obj;
```

is equivalent to this

```
const a = obj.a;
const b = obj.b;
```

Further, if you want to use a different variable name than the prop's name, you can do it like so

```
const {a, b: c} = obj;
```

which is equivalent to

```
const a = obj.a;
const c = obj.b;
```

which is what your `{ name, category: categoryName }` is doing here.

Answer (score 1):

When you just give one value in object `{value}` the **Key** property will be same as name of the variable ( **variable name works as placeholder for key**)

```js
let a = 'Value'
console.log({a})
```

If you want to define different name you can do it by defining both **Key** and **Value**.

```js
let a = 'value'
console.log({key: a})
```

> My question was more for this portion category: categoryName. I see
>   that categoryName is assigned the value of category. How does this
>   happen?

```
let var1 = {a:1}
let {a} = var1
```

is same as 
   let var1 = {a:1}
   let a = var1.a

And this one is

```
let var1 = {a:1}
let {a:b} = var1
```

is same as

```
let var1 = {a:1}
let b = var1.a
```

[image]

Comment: My question was more for this portion `category: categoryName`. I see that categoryName is assigned the value of category. How does this happen?

Comment: @PunyaslokaParida i have added a example to make you understand more what i meant by my comment. you can see the update

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature available since the ES6 (or ES2015) called Shorthand notation.

If you want to define an object who's keys have the same name as the variables passed-in as properties, you can use the shorthand and simply pass the key name

In ES5 (older syntax) we need to use key:value as you said. An example:

```
var name = 'John';
var surname = 'Matthew';
var age = 45;

var myObject = {
  name : name,
  surname : surname,
  age : age
};

console.log(myObject);
```

In ES6+ (or ES2015+) we dont need to use key:value if we want to keep the attributes' name as the variable passed-in. Like this:

```
let name = 'John';
let surname = 'Matthew';
let age = 45;

let myObject = {
  name,
  surname,
  age
};

console.log(myObject);
```